# Dynamically call a method from unknown source file

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

I need to call a method from one class to another class whose class name will be taken from file (dynamically)

Example:

> 1. I have a file named Source1.h/Source1.m (both are objective C class files)
> 2. I have another file names Source2.h/Source2.m (both are objective C class files)

I can able to call a method from Source2 class file. But the name "Source2" will be taken from a text file and the method to which i have to call is known by me. Hence how do i call the method from unknown class file.

Eg:

```
unknownClassName *a = [[unknownClassName alloc] init];
[self a];
```

I know the Method "a". But the `unknownClassName` will taken taken from a text file in runtime.

Is it possible to do like this?

Comment: what about `NSClassFromString(@"unknownClassName")`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this

```
id unknownClassObject = [[NSClassFromString(@"unknownClassName") alloc] init];
[unknownClassObject a];
```